# did i understand the below EPI variant question correctly?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Let m be a postive integer and L a sorted single linked list of integers. for each integer k, if k appears more than m times in L, remove all node from L containing k.

as per my understanding if the input is

L = 1 --> 2 -->2-->2 -->2 --> 3--> Null 
K =2

so any number should not be more than 2 times. here 2 is repeating 3 times, hence it should remove all 2. so output should be like

output : 1-->3--> NULL

when i refer this solution in internet someone posted answer saying output should be like

1-->2-->3--> NULL.

could you please post understanding about this problem ?

i know this is very silly question. please try if you have time. if you know solution also good.

where i can find EPI problem variant solution

Comment: from my side the response in this case should be the one you posted, `output : 1-->3--> NULL`. Said to remove all multiple occurrences.(the requirement is not to keep distinct, each 1 time)

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, need to check occurrences and create a new list based on.
Now if need only non-repetitive or just distinct need to clear yourself.

```
    List<Integer> l = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> result2 = new LinkedList<>();

    Collections.addAll(l, 1,2,2,3);
    
    //non-repetitive
    for(Integer i : l.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList()))
    {
        if(Collections.frequency(l, i)==1)
        {
            result.add(i);
        }
    }
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
    
    //distinct (or non-repetitive)
    //just to have an alternative approach for counting
    Map<Integer, Long> counts =l.stream().
                       collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
    for(Integer i: counts.keySet())
    {
        //non-repetitive
        //if(counts.get(i)==1) result2.add(i);
        result2.add(i);
    }
    result2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Result:

```
non-repetitive: 1,3
distinct: 1,2,3
```

Note: This is a working solution, not necessary the optimal one. Also didn't follow description to work just on initial list. Since didn't provide any code should adapt yourself.

Another approach can be to iterate over initial-list keeping track of previous element and proceed based on and the current. (keep or delete nodes)

Answer (score 0):

i implemented this solution. please check

```
public Node remove(Node head, int k) {
        Node iter = head;
        Node prev = null;
        while (iter != null) {
            int i = 1;
            Node distrinct = iter.next;
            while (distrinct != null && distrinct.data == iter.data) {
                i++;
                distrinct = distrinct.next;
            }
            /*there is no element within given range */
            if (prev == null && distrinct == null)
                return null;

            if (i >= k) {
                if (prev == null) {
                    head = distrinct;
                } else {
                    prev.next = distrinct;
                }
            } else {
                prev = iter;
            }
            iter = distrinct;
        }
        return head;
    }
```

Comment: First you should tell if from your view is working or not. If there are issues then maybe it's better to open a new post with. Also maybe considering posting on code review and not here.  From what I can see, you just added the remove method which is just a part of initial problem (how do you retrieve k? what's the custom list implementation ?). Note, initial question was if your assumption is fine and me answer. Kindly try to add all missing parts and enhance your question maybe on a new post.

Comment: Hint : Consider to solve in just in one list loop.(not finding a k, then iterate again against, etc). Maybe method signature should be `remove(Node head)`.